# Why the HystrixTimeoutException is thrown when I set execution.timeout.enabled=false

Tags: hystrix

The hystrix version in my application is `1.5.12.@Hystrix`. The command is used like this:

```
@HystrixCommand(groupKey = "myGroupKey", commandKey = "myCommandKey", fallbackMethod = "myFallBack").
```

The value of `hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled` is false in the config file, which means that the hystrix timeout is forbidden, but the HystrixTimeoutException is thrown by a thread named HystrixTimer-2.